# Fragments and AsyncTasks

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Since a fragment can be unattached from the activity at any moment and you can get an null pointer if you call `getActivity()` or `getView()` in the post execute or when a broadcast is received. Whats the correct way of proceed with that?

Keep a reference to the views in the `onCreateView()` and update them in the lifecicle calls? check every time if the getActivity() returns a not null ref? use isAdded()?

Is there some place where I can be sure the getActivity() method returns not a not null value? like within onCreate / onResume etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess this is obvious, but in cases where it can be null, then check for null. Otherwise, try to use `onAttach(Activity)` which is called when the Fragment is associated with the Activity. Obviously, the Activity won't be null there.